# R: Getting Unix-like linebreak LF writing files with cat()

Tags: r, windows, file-io, linefeed

I try to write a character vector to a textfile under Windows 7 / R 3.2.2 x64, and I want unix LF - not Windows CRLF:

```
v <- c("a","b","c")
cat(nl,file="textfile.txt",sep="\n")
```

writes

```
> a[CRLF] 
> b[CRLF] 
> c[CRLF]
```

---

```
cat(paste(nl,sep="\n",collapse="\n"),file="t2.txt")
```

writes

```
> a[CRLF] 
> b[CRLF] 
> c
```

I have also tried write.table(eol="\n") - unsuccessfully as it seems to use cat internally.

I have looked for other workarounds; 
I tried to find sth. in R\src\main\scan.c, locating the relevant code in line 387ff.

Anyone who knows how I can get UNIX-like LF in my output file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to open a file connection in "binary" mode (instead of "text" mode) to prevent system-dependent encoding of the end-of-line:

```
v <- c("a","b","c")
f <- file("textfile.txt", open="wb")
cat(v,file=f,sep="\n")
close(f)
```

Answer (score 1):

based on the answer from @xb

```
converter <- function(infile){
    print(infile)
    txt <- readLines(infile)
    f <- file(infile, open="wb")
    cat(txt, file=f, sep="\n")
    close(f)
}
```