# cat appends CR to output in R

Tags: r

I've read in a text file, which in the global env, looks good:

[image]

Note: I am on windows, and the linebreaks are \r\n.

It looks like it was read in properly, because if I look at the textfile in notepad++ I see the symbols:

[image]

However, if I try to write the file back using `cat`, I get additional {CR} bytes thrown in:

```
cat(txtFile, file="out.txt", append="FALSE")
```

[image]

This leads to the resulting text file appearing 'double spaced.' Very annoying, and I don't know why `cat()` is doing that.  I've also tried `writeLines`, but any time it tries to write the string to the file, it just puts the {CR}'s before the {CRLF}.

Does anyone know how to stop this behavior?

Comment: read up `?cat`. cat by DEFAULT adds a sep = " ". try your code with `cat(txtFile, file="out.txt", append="FALSE", sep ="")` and see if that meets your expectations

Comment: That didn't work. I believe sep="" will be used to concatenate  vectors or lists of strings together with a separator. In this case, it was a single string, read from a file.  I want to just write out the read-in string back, and I expect read-in -> write-out on an unmodified string value should result in the same output, but it does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution here was similar to the answer found here: [R: Getting Unix-like linebreak LF writing files with cat()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32906886/r-getting-unix-like-linebreak-lf-writing-files-with-cat?rq=1)

```
    f<-file("out.txt", open="wb");
    cat(txtFile,file=f,sep="");
    close(f);
```

Resulting text file output in notepad++:
[image]